# Customize domain url for WSO2 API Gateway

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We have a setup of API Manager on a windows machine which is inside a enterprise private network. We want to map the API Gateway url to a domain name.
Gateway URL inside the private network - https://10.1.x.y:8243
At load balancer we have done the mapping to redirect requests for https://xyz.abc.com to gateway url. But gateway is not able to listen to the incoming request. 
Please let me know what more information can I provide here, if required, or please let me know the ways I can resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: From the load balancer check the connectivity to the gateway node.

Comment: I checked and it is working fine. Only the apache server for the gateway is not able to receive

Comment: You can check the http_access log which resides in gateway node (wso2am-2.0.0/repository/logs/). It logs the incoming requests to the gateway node. Can u explain the deployment? Firewalls could be blocking the requests.